# How to calculate my apk hash programmatically with Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing an app that needs to verify data tampering such as changes on critical files.
What I'm basically trying to do is calculate the hash of my apk within the Dart code(while the user uses the app), so I can send it to verification on my api.

There's some way to do this? I've searched a lot but I only find ways to generate the hash from the terminal or native ways using java.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access the APK file from within Dart.

What you can do is calculate the hash in Java/Kotlin and access it via a [MethodChannel](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-kotlin-tab).